# Bottom content cutoff using overflow: auto; and jscrollpane

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

Because of a rotated content area, textoverflow, and a -webkit issue about the scroll bar not showing properly I've decided to use jscrollpane.  For initial issue:  [Original Issue question to Sitepoint.](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/css-53/vert-scroll-bar-overflow-auto-not-working-chrome-761462-new-post.html)

To prevent all that extra css code to create my own scrollbar for -webkit browsers I decided to use jscrollpane.  It works accept for one major issue:  The bottom several lines of text remain invisible!  Please see:  [overflow:  auto; with jscrollpane, but cutting off bottom text.](http://test1.chuprinastudios.com/resume2.php)  How do I make it scrollable enabling all of the content to be visible?

Any help is appreciated.

PChuprina

Comment: I have the same problem in webkit browsers. Have you determined a solution?

Answer (score 2):

jScrollPane has some options for solving this:

---

```
autoReinitialise:true
```

(adds processing overhead.. use only if necessary)

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/auto_reinitialise.html

---

```
reinitialise()
```

(manually update pane size)

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/dynamic_content.html

---

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

This looks like a simple problem of timing. You are/something is altering the content of the scroll pane after the `jsScrollPane()` function has run.

First try simply including it in a `$(document).ready()` function. If that doesn't work go through your functions and check to see if any javascript is altering the size of that container and add `jsScrollPane()` as a callback.

Pretty sure the first will work for you though :)

Comment: Hi @Inrbob,
Unfortunately your fix didn't work.  Not sure whether I implemented the $(document).ready() function.  The code to implement jscrollpane is:

$(function(){
$('#resume').jScrollPane();
});

Also there doesn't seem to be any other functions altering the size of the container.  The only other javascript is for Google analytics.  Any more help would definately be appreciated and a learning experience.  Thanks.  PChuprina

Comment: hmm, interesting. If you open up your site in chrome, hit ctrl+shift+j, go to console, type in `$('#resume').jScrollPane();` and hit enter it should display the correct scroll. You have a script.js file - can you not add your initialisation code here? Final option - it could be because of your images loading. If adding to `$(document).ready(function(){})` in script.js doesn't work try creating a new function `$(window).load(function(){$('#resume').jScrollPane();})`

Comment: I think Inrbob is right, but I've found some weird behaviour of jScrollPane. I had the same issue. My images had padding property set to 6px, which was no calculated in overall height of enclosing div. jScrollPane initializator just ignored that property of an image and enclosing div was shorter than expected by (2x6px)12px.