# Dynamically changing the height of a div based on content

Tags: javascript, css, html

So I am trying to make a website and have a popup window/box DIV that appears after clicking something. This popup DIV contains text/content, let's name it "Locations," as per my website's design. This Locations Popup DIV has a fixed height and width, and consequently, there is a vertical scroll bar I've created to scroll down and read the text. I would like to add more content to this popup but unfortunately, the text is being cutoff, and the scroll does not continue scrolling down. I have set a pretty large value for the margin/padding in the DIV to make this work for a very long page length, but it is very inefficient and poor programming.

How can I set the style of a div to the height of the total HTML document (which is the dyanamic, changing factor here) using JavaScript or CSS so I can do this intelligently and properly? I don't want to have to manually do this, as the longer the HTML Document becomes if I choose, I will always have to go back and either change the margin/padding value in CSS or do something to the JavaScript.

Below is the CSS for it:

```
/* Pop Up */
#popupAbout, #popupLocations, #popupContact, #popupBlog {
    height: 600px;
    width: 900px;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    border: 2px solid #cecece;
    z-index: 15;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#popupAbout p, #popupLocations p, #popupContact p, #popupBlog p {
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
#popupAbout h1, #popupLocations h1, #popupContact h1, #popupBlog h1 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #D3D3D3;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#popupAboutClose, #popupLocationsClose, #popupContactClose, #popupBlogClose {
    right: 6px;
    top: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

And the appropriate JavaScript:

```
//Locations Page Pop Up
            var popupLocationsStatus = 0;

            function loadPopupLocations(){
                if(popupLocationsStatus==0){
                    $("#popupLocations").fadeIn("slow");
                    popupLocationsStatus = 1;
                }
            }

            function disablePopupLocations(){
                if(popupLocationsStatus==1){
                    $("#popupLocations").fadeOut("slow");
                    popupLocationsStatus = 0;
                }
            }

            function centerPopupLocations(){
                var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
                var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
                var popupLocationsHeight = $("#popupLocations").height();
                var popupLocationsWidth = $("#popupLocations").width();
                $("#popupLocations").css({
                    "position": "absolute",
                    "top": windowHeight/2-popupLocationsHeight/2,
                    "left": windowWidth/2-popupLocationsWidth/2
                });
            }


            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#popupLocations").fadeOut();
                popupLocationsStatus = 0;
                $("#Locations").click(function(){
                $("#popupLocations").css({
                    "visibility": "visible" });
                    disablePopupAbout();
                    disablePopupContact();                  
                    centerPopupLocations();
                    loadPopupLocations();
                });
                $("#popupLocationsClose").click(function(){
                    disablePopupLocations();
                });
            });
            $(function()
            {
                $('#popupLocations').jScrollPane();
                $('.popupLocations').jScrollPane(
                    {
                        showArrows: true,
                        horizontalGutter: 10
                    }
                );
            });
```

Here is the screenshot I've saved to give a better look at what I am talking about exactly (looking at the bottom of the popup window where the text is being cutoff):

[My Website Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEh1E.jpg)

Everyone may view my work so far at: www.zaheeruddinsyed.com, to see exactly what I am talking about.

Comment: holy wall of text - you get more help if your question is brief and to the point.

Comment: True, but I believe providing much information as possible avoids confusion and/or the need to request info later down the line. It can only help those who are trying to help, by my understanding.

Comment: In your code you are referencing `.jScrollPane()`. Is this your own javascript function or are you using the **[jScrollPane plugin](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)**?

Comment: Everyone may view my work so far at: www.zaheeruddinsyed.com, to see exactly what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I believe you're looking for [`overflow: auto`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) property. Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uZhq3/).</s>

If you want to achieve the scrollbar like on sample image, you'll have to play around with css, [here](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) is tutorial on how to apply custom style to scrollbar.

Btw, if you want to make popup window, you might want to look at [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/), which, in my opinion, looks really good and most of work is already done! The only downside might be that you have to use it with jQuery, but it's already used on most of the webpages today.

---

**Edit**

When I've looked at page source, I found the problem in less than a minute. The content of your popup div isn't scrolling to the bottom, it stops for some reason.

This question is similar: [Bottom content cutoff using overflow: auto; and jscrollpane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258178/bottom-content-cutoff-using-overflow-auto-and-jscrollpane)

Try and put this code in JavaScript console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + (<kbd>J</kbd> in Chrome, <kbd>K</kbd> in Firefox):

```
$("#popupLocations .jspPane").css("top","-800px")
```

It scrolls down to the bottom where it should. I know that this doesn't solve your problem just yet, but I think I've found a solution (I'm not sure because I can't test it myself). But if you look at that other question, the solution is using `autoReinitialise:true`. You can try it right away by running this in JavaScript console:

```
$('.popupLocations').jScrollPane({
                        showArrows: true,
                        horizontalGutter: 10,
                        autoReinitialise:true
                    }
                );
```

Of course you'll have to put it in your file where you're initializing jScrollPane if you want it to work correctly every time you refresh the page.

And why do you have 2 `$(document).ready(function()...)` and 2 `$(function()...` (which is the same) definitions in your file? You should put all the code in one function, which will be called when the DOM is loaded. And for the sake of your users UX, try to reduce the images and files, also try to avoid using millions of different js plugins. It took me almost 11s (according to network profiler) to load for the first time and I have 100Mb/s uplink, I can't imagine someone with mobile internet. The webpage makes over 100 requests, a lot of them are 1x1px pngs. If all that is really necessary, you might want to look into compressing and bundling. It depends on what back-end framework you'll be using. I can say that ASP.NET MVC 4 provides very simple bundle manager but I'm sure that PHP or rails provide something similar.

Comment: Sorry, but that wasn't what I was talking about. I have already achieved the scroll bar effect. That sample image is the one I have created. The DIV is not dynamically changing the height so that it can take in more content from the HTML Document Element. If you look at my sample image, you will see at the bottom where the text is being cutoff, and the scroll bar is not shrinking as to accommodate for such. I need to make it so that the text is not cutoff, and I will not need to go back and forth to change the margin/padding tediously as so.

Comment: And yes, thank you for the Popup Window info. But the screenshot is already a popup window, so thus, I have also achieved that as well.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought the link was from some random page... Thanks for correcting the link name, it makes much more sense now. For the popup window, I know that you have it but fancybox auto resizes and does all the work for you, you'll just have to add the content.

Comment: No problem. And unfortunately, that's not the kind of answer I'm looking for. It would be helpful if you could read in entirety what I have posted exactly. Thank you nonetheless

Comment: I'm sorry, I was on phone and just wanted to help quickly, I've misunderstood what you'd like to achieve. I've read through your question carefully now and I know what is your problem, but unfortunately, I can't tell what could be the problem. It would help to see a jsfiddle with whole code, not just the js and css part. And a hint for your styling: use classes you can assign a class to all of those popups and style the class instead of each id individually. It also helps at js for easier manipulation, e.g. you could hide all elements with one selector instead of calling all those functions.

Comment: That's fine, and thanks for understanding. The problem, like I've said, is that the Popup DIV is not dynamically changing the height to allow more content from the HTML Document to be exposed. I have HTML Content from my HTML file, (which I will post on the jsfiddle as you've requested), which is being cutoff in the Popup DIV. I have changed the margin/padding of the Popup DIV to allow for more HTML content (text) to be shown, but I do not want to do this everytime, as it is tedious, and not smart programming. If you look at my snapshot, please look at the bottom near the vertical scroll bar.

Comment: You should add the link in the original question so it's easier to see for anybody else looking at this question. And you've forgot to add jquery and something to display the popup when clicked. I've fixed that for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/YzTss/

Comment: Ah okay thank you for that. Were you able to fix my original issue?

Comment: No, because there is no issue, at least from what I see. If you can deploy what you have on one of the free web hosting pages and link your actual project here, it might help. The jsfiddle project is missing the images and probably the font. If you don't want to show the whole webpage, you can play around with the fiddle and reproduce the error you're having. Without seeing the error, I can't really try to fix it, sorry.

Comment: Everyone may view my work so far at: www.zaheeruddinsyed.com. As you can see, when clicking on the Locations Popup, the text content is being cutoff at the bottom. And furthermore, I viewed my website on different browsers, such as Chrome for example, on a different system, a Sony VAIO, as opposed to a MAC which I am viewing it on now. The resolutions are different and consequently, another issue I have run into is that my website is not dynamically changing to adapt to different resolutions/systems in general.

Comment: The Popup Windows are not centered in the middle of the screen and are being cutoff at the top.